# Wrap several div with other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapall

I have several div as following:

```
<div id='id1'>blabla</div>
<div id='id2'>blabla</div>
<div id='id3'>blabla</div>
<div id='id4'>blabla</div>
<div id='id5'>blabla</div>
<div id='id6'>blabla</div>
```

And I would like to add a new div (`<div id='newdiv'>`) in order to wrap the div I specify.

For example before 'id3' and after 'id5'.
So we obtain:

```html
<div id='id1'>blabla</div>
<div id='id2'>blabla</div>
<div id='newdiv'>
  <div id='id3'>blabla</div>
  <div id='id4'>blabla</div>
  <div id='id5'>blabla</div>
</div>
<div id='id6'>blabla</div>
```

Do you know jQuery code to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Use [jQuery .wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) :

```
$('#id3, #id4, #id5').wrapAll('<div id="newdiv" />')
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/K4HVR/

Answer (score 3):

Probably a simple plugin to make it more flexible, reusable:

```
$.fn.customWrap = function (end, wrapperDivAttr) {
    this.nextUntil(end).next().addBack().add(this).wrapAll($('<div/>', wrapperDivAttr));
}

$('#id3').customWrap('#id5', { id: 'newDiv'}); // call the function on the startelement, specify the end elements selector and attribute obj.
```

**[nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)** to get all the divs until the end div, then next to select the end div as well, and **[addback()](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/)** to add the previous elements (nextUntil ones) to the collection and then **[add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)** to select the start div as well and then **[wrapAll](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)** of them.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eRFaF/)**

Comment: Thanks @Sushanth, otherwise it becomes so obvious.. :)

Comment: @PSL i answer the question of the OP ;) but i like the idea of a plugin, but you are missing something, changed it a little bit : http://jsfiddle.net/EVc46/1/

Answer (score 0):

In a bit of a hurry so this is untested but something like this?

```
 $("#id3, #id4, #id5").wrapAll('<div id="newdiv" />');
```

EDIT: Oh damn, looks like Karl-André beat me to it!